# Querying date/time on 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have a column date and column time on my PostgreSQL table. I wish to make a query, to filter rows that are not expired based on date and time. I tried this, but it does not works and returns an error `Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) syntax error at or nea`:

```
from q in Line, where: fragment("date ? + time ? > NOW()", q.date, q.time)
```

Comment: Would not single quotes around values help: `fragment("date '?' + time '?' > NOW()", q.date, q.time)`?

Comment: Tried that already @AlekseiMatiushkin but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem can be solved by not using `time` and `date` prefixes:

```
from q in Line, where: fragment("? + ? > NOW()", q.date, q.time)
```

or even

```
from q in Line, where: q.date + q.time < fragment("NOW()")
```

Provided, your columns have the correct data type

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out, just forgot to update the answer. Even better you can use `fragment("date + time > NOW()")`

Comment: Nice, however, keep in mind that this could lead to name-clashes AFAIK, for example when joining two tables with `date` and `time` defined.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you need to run a standard query or if you are filtering via some GUI, but `time` and `date` types can be combined together via simple addition. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

The following code:

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT* FROM (VALUES 
        ('11:29:10'::time,'03-18-2019'::date),
        ('11:29:10'::time,'03-18-2021'::date)
    ) t ("time","date")
)
SELECT * FROM q WHERE q.time+q.date > NOW()
```

Should only print the date in the future, which is what you are trying to achieve.
Hope this helps!